# how to get the entire html source code of a website using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I used file_get_content() and got only the contents in the website but I want the whole html code of the webpage. So how can i get the entire html source code of a webpage by entering only the url of the webpage and echo it?

Comment: What is the difference between "the contents in the website" and "the whole html code of the webpage"?

Comment: You did get the whole HTML, but when you printed it, the browser obviously translated it into visual.

Comment: The site u are fetching is prolly fetching extra data with ajax/javascrip

Comment: I used this curl function and got the html source code..I want some other method to get the same htmlb source code..                                                $curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://example');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
$query =  htmlentities($query);
echo $query;

Comment: @CheranPrakash — You have no described *two* different methods which you are using to get the source code of the page. Why do you want a third one?

Comment: I see no reason for downvoting this question, unless it's duplicated. It's a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @IvanIvković — The comments on the question have two people asking for clarification because its meaning is unclear, and one person who thinks that the problem doesn't exist and the OP is misinterpreting what they are seeing. It is not a good question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can use apps like Internet Download Manager (IDM)